# iphone simulator & videos

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

i just want to know is it possible to save video in iphone simulator iphone 3.1
 if yes then how??

Answer (score 2):

If by save video you mean capture the simulator's screen then "no" is the answer. You can use some sort of screen capture software and crop the video to fit the screen. I would recommend [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm)